# Issues with build in Carbide C++ 2.0

Tags: c++, symbian, s60, carbide

I'm building my application and when I try to run it on the emulator, I get this error.

```
Creation Time   Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1254339868582   BLDMAKE ERROR: Directory "\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\" does not exist   ZeFirst     Unknown C/C++ Problem
```

The folder does exist and does have the necessary rights.

The console has the following set of warning messages

```
warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV6.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms
warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV6T2.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms
warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV7A.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms
```

Comment: Do you get the same result from the command line, i.e.
bldmake bldfiles
abld build winscw udeb

Would be helpful if you posted the full build output, I think.

Comment: here's the console log

part 1 - 

perl.exe -S bldmake.pl bldfiles winscw  
WARNING: EPOCROOT does not specify an existing directory
warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV6.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms
warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV6T2.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms

Comment: part 2 - 


warning: "C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\GCCEV7A.bsf" Invalid BSF specification - customization restricted to ARMV5, ABIv2 and valid BSF platforms
BLDMAKE ERROR: Directory "\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\" does not exist

=== BLDMAKE Command failed with error code 1 ===

Comment: You can safely ignore the BSF thing.

The bldmake error seems to suggest that your %EPOCROOT% environment variable is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What other development tools do you have installed on your computer?

Is there a chance your path environment variable is in the wrong order and you're not using the correct version of the compiler, for example?

Feel free to post your path, it can only provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try this:

Subst a drive to C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\

```
Start, Run...
subst x: C:\S60\devices\Nokia_N97_SDK_v1.0\
```

Then in carbide, set your SDK to point to this subst location.

```
Window, Preferences, Carbide C++, SDK .. 
Change the paths to use "x:\"  rather than C:\...
```

Delete any imported projects in Carbide

```
Select project, right-click, delete.
(Do NOT click the tick box that is displayed).
```

Re-import your project

```
File, Import, x:\.....\bld.inf
```

Comment: In Windows XP (and older) a symbolic link can be created without using the ancient SUBST.
However after each IDE restart the preference for SDK root will revert to its original location.

Comment: You've comented 5 years after I wrote this. :).  (PS - I believe the Symbian Code base required that it was located in the root of the drive, which is why subst was used. However, its all immaterial now.. *sob*)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem once.

If you have been able to build and launch the eumlator on earlier occasions, then the only solution that worked for me was to re-install the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Techeretic,

make sure that your workspace is located in the same driver partition (C:) of your Symbian SDK installation. If don't try changing it.

Sometimes I solved that problem by changing .pkg file's content to use a relative path. For example:

```
;Files to install
;You should change the source paths to match that of your environment
;<source> <destination>
"$(EPOCROOT)Epoc32\release\$(PLATFORM)\$(TARGET)\MyApp.exe"     -"!:\sys\bin\MyApp.exe"
"$(EPOCROOT)Epoc32\data\z\resource\apps\MyApp.r01"      -"!:\resource\apps\MyApp.r01"
"$(EPOCROOT)Epoc32\data\z\private\10003a3f\apps\MyApp_reg.r01"  -"!:\private\10003a3f\import\apps\MyApp_reg.r01"
"$(EPOCROOT)epoc32\data\z\resource\apps\MyApp_aif.mif" -"!:\resource\apps\MyApp_aif.mif"
"$(EPOCROOT)epoc32\data\z\resource\apps\MyApp.mbm" -"!:\resource\apps\MyApp.mbm"
```

Hope it helps.